# Excel function throws exception when set by code behind. Works when used in excel

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, excel-addins, addin-express

I've defined my own Excel function (called *ADXExcelFunctionDeescriptor*). The method stub looks like following:

```
public static object ExecuteMyFunction(object values, object tagName)
{ // Some code here }
```

The method receives an array of double values and a string, called name.
In the design view my *ADXExcelFunctionDeescriptor* looks like following:

[image]

I call and set the function by the following lines of code:

```
var formula = string.Format(@"={0}({1};{2})", Temp.FORMULA_NAME, this.DataRangeTextBox.Text, tagCaption);
resultRange.set_Value(Type.Missing, formula);
resultRange.Formula = resultRange.Value;
```

This will result in an exception! The exception looks like the following:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException occurred
  HResult=-2146827284
  Message=Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
  Source=""
  ErrorCode=-2146827284
  StackTrace:
       bei System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
       bei Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.set_Value(Object RangeValueDataType, Object )
       bei bb.ExcelToolbar.Controls.bbControl.ApplyFormula(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\xx\yy\zz\bb\bb.ExcelToolbar\Controls\bbControlcs:Zeile 88.
  InnerException:
```

Further, if I don't pass the tagName parameter the function returns a result without any exception or error.

```
var formula = string.Format(@"={0}({1})", Temp.FORMULA_NAME, this.DataRangeTextBox.Text, tagCaption);
resultRange.set_Value(Type.Missing, formula);
resultRange.Formula = resultRange.Value;
```

So I think it has something to do with the string parameter.
I also tried to surround the string parameter with " or ' characters but no change so far.

Further if I type the function directly into Excel it works without any problems. So, for example, if I type in the following formula in Excel:

```
=Temp.DoSomething(B2:B13;"Flow")
```

Maybe I miss out something or doing something wrong?

Comment: what is the inner exception?

Comment: @israelaltar: The inner exception is NULL.

Comment: Have you tried using a comma ={0}({1},{2}) or colon in your formula?

Comment: Your UDF appears to be set up to accept 2 `object` arguments, would it not be better to use `Excel.Range` and `string` as the types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't look like you're adding quotes around that second parameter tagCaption in your constructed UDF string formula. There should be quotes around that value.

```
var formula = string.Format(@"={0}({1};""{2}"")",Temp.FORMULA_NAME, 
                              this.DataRangeTextBox.Text, tagCaption);
```

Also: see Chris Neilsen's comment here: [Excel - Inserting formula with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584132/excel-inserting-formula-with-vba)

> in VBA `.Formula`, `.FormulaArray` and `.FormulaR1C1` use international
>   seperator (ie `,`) and `.FormulaLocal`, and `.FormulaR1C1Local` use the
>   language of the user (so can use `;` if that is your language setting).
>   So for this OP assigning to `.FormulaArray` it is correct to say always
>   use `,`